# Unity IOC Container. How to resolve instance from IOC container outside of the scope where container was created?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I am new to IOC containers and i am trying to understand how to use them. I understand the concept but I having issues on how to practically apply it. Currently, I am using Unity ioc container to register an instance of a RestClient for a web api wrapper class and then injecting said instance to a class that handles the different requests. see code below:

```
var myClient = new RestClient();
var iocContainer = new UnityContainer();
iocContainer.RegisterInstance(myClient);
iocContainer.RegisterType<MyWrapperClass>(
new InjectionConstructor(iocContainer.Resolve<RestClient>()));
```

This code is happening in the OnStartup file of my wpf application. If I want to get that object that was register I know i can call `iocContainer.Resolve<MyWrapperClass>()` however, if how can I resolve that object in a different class where the Ioc does not live?

Hopefully my explanation makes sense. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The basic idea of **dependeny injection** is to **inject any dependency**. If you want to use something then inject it (instance or factory)

Comment: *"How to resolve instance from IOC container outside of the scope where container was created?"* - You never use the IOC container outside of the scope where container was created. See Sir Rufo's comment on how instances are "resolved" (they are *injected*).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use a DI Container is to use the [Register Resolve Release pattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/09/29/TheRegisterResolveReleasepattern). Instead of sprinkling your entire code base with calls to `container.Resolve`, you should have one line of code in your code base that calls `Resolve`. That line of code, then, composes the entire object graph that implements the behaviour of the application.

(Really, you don't need a DI Container to do that, and I consider [Pure DI](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) a much simpler solution to the same problem.)

When an object needs to talk to another object, let it request the dependency via its constructor, e.g.:

```
public MainWindow(IDep dep) { /*...*/ }
```

It's been a decade since I've last looked at WPF, but the first edition of my book [Dependency Injection in .NET](https://blog.ploeh.dk/ref/diidn) has a section that covers WPF composition (and a chapter on Unity, too). That edition is also available as a free eBook with the [latest edition of the book](https://blog.ploeh.dk/dippp).

Answer (score 0):

> however, if how can I resolve that object in a different class where the Ioc does not live?

You need to get a reference to the container one way or another.

You could for example define a static property in the `App` class:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public static IUnityContainer Container { get; } = new UnityContainer();

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var myClient = new RestClient();
        var iocContainer = Container;
        iocContainer.RegisterInstance(myClient);
        iocContainer.RegisterType<MyWrapperClass>(
            new InjectionConstructor(iocContainer.Resolve<RestClient>()));
    }
}
```

You can then easily resolve a type from a component in your app like this:

```
var wrapperClass = App.Container.Resolve<MyWrapperClass>();
```

Comment: Just a remark: that's the Service Locator and it's considered [an antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Comment: By some. In this context, it's probably the easiest way to resolve dependencies from a container which was what the question was all about.

Comment: The service locator is used as a way to get rid of dependencies in your code but instead of that it adds one dependency - service locator itself! Well done. 

Comment: Yes, it adds one dependency (to an interface) from which you can resolve the others. That's similar (well) to how a messenger works for example.

Comment: You need to store a reference to the container and use it resolve the registered types somewhere.

Comment: Well, in my applications any dependecy gets **injected** (mainly through constructor). No tight coupling with a static whatever from wherever. If you want DI then do DI. If not, well go for it, but do not call it DI.

Comment: You need to resolve the dependency from the container before it gets injected though. That's the issue here, isn't it?

Comment: No, I copy it for you: *how can I resolve that object in a different class where the Ioc does not live?* - And the question is tagged with **dependency injection** - a Service Locator is **not** dependency **injection**

Comment: No, it's used to resolve the dependencies to be injected. Or where do you get your dependencies from?

Comment: Obviousy, you cannot resolve an object without the container.

Comment: Well I do use a DI-Container for DI, but I do not have such a static Container because that is a dependency and not dependency injection.

Comment: Static or not, "you need to get a reference to the container one way or another" as I wrote in the first sentence of my answer.

Comment: @SirRufo: Why don't you provide your answer with your suggestion of how to resolve the issue of resolving the dependencies?

Comment: My *antipattern* remark was not to criticise the answer (which is good) but to let the OP know that there's a broader context. The better solution is even mentioned in linked article - it's a local resolver, independent of anything and which is configured in the composition root. There are multiple correct approaches, I've blogged [about one some time ago](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2016/01/di-factories-and-composition-root.html).